# Playwright wait for icon event completed

Tags: playwright, playwright-test

I got a page like below. There is an action bar. When I clicked the action button, the icon will rotate and then reload the page. I tried `waitforloadstate` and it did not work. Currently I can only `waitfortimeout`.

```
<div id="line-flag" class="action-button" data-toggle="tooltip" title data-original-title="Flag">
  <i class="fas fa-flag">
    ::before
  </i>
  <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm" role="status">
    <span class="sr-only"Loading...</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

How can I rotate the button?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple options for how to wait for it on UI.

```js
// Wait for spinner not visible
await expect(page.locator(".spinner-border", { hasText: "Loading..." })).toBeHidden();

// Wait for status text changed
await expect(page.getByRole("status")).not.toContainText("Loading...");

...
```

Also, you may need to add verifications that the spinner exists before checking its absence.

Comment: All icons have such text. But I found the style attribute could be used to identify. Thanks for your answer. It's very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This will wait until loading spinner disappears:

```
await expect(locatorOfSpinner).toHaveCount(0);
```

**Note**: This is very handy piece of code to resolve lot of general sync/loading issues.

Comment: It seems .toHaveCount() will count the hidden element. I used .toHidden() instead. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: It depends upon your locator properties selected , so it will count per your locator definition.